# Problems outputting a ++ and ++ a in one statement

Tags: c++

## include

int main()
{

```
using std::endl;
using std::cout;
int a=0;
cout << a++ << endl << ++a << endl;
int b=0;
cout << b++ << endl;
cout << ++b;
```

}

The output is 1 2 0 2.
Why does a ++ output 1? Shouldn't it be 0?
Can anyone tell me the principle！

Comment: It's very complicated because the rules on this have changed several times with different versions of C++. If you search you will find that this question has already been asked *hundreds* of times. Just don't write code like this. There's no point to it, that's all you need to know.

Comment: what compiler are you using? both g++ and clang++ produced 0 2 0 2 on my machine

Comment: I use colon and vs on my machine.

Comment: I won't write code this way